# Make line longer/extrude vertex along line

Tags: extrude, lines

I have an object with a line like so:
[image]

I would like to extrude the end vertex from the line at the same angle like so
[image]

or alternatively make the line longer like so:
[image]

How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have enough ways to extend the edge now, but here is another just to show that it is possible with changing the *Transform Orientation* while restricting the extension to X or Y and being able to type in absolute values for how far you want the vertex to move. With this method it does not matter if the edge is aligned with any other geometry or just randomly pointing outwards:

1. Select the edge which you want to extend.

   [image: select edge]
2. Instead of pressing <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>, <kbd>Numpad 3</kbd> or <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> to align the view to the global *Front*, *Right* or *Top* view instead use these number keys in combination with <kbd>Shift</kbd> to align to the selected edge. It depends on the orientation of the edge now which to use best, just switch to a view where the edge is either horizontal or vertical in the viewport, in my example I used <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 3</kbd>.

   [image: shift + numpad]
3. Now switch the *Transform Orientation* to *View*. With this option you can restrict moving/extruding to move horizontally by pressing <kbd>X</kbd> and vertically by pressing <kbd>Y</kbd>.

   [image: transform orientation view]
4. Select the vertex at the end of the edge and either press <kbd>G</kbd> to move it or <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude it. In my case the edge is aligned horizontally, so I need to limit the movement to only go left or right. I want to move it 1 m to the left which is in -X direction, so I enter <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>-</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Return</kbd>.

   [image: move on view X]

And that's it, now you can switch back the *Transformation Orientation* to whatever you need and view the object from which angle you want.

Comment: This should be pretty much the same as just creating custom transform orientation from the edge and using it, but somehow it really feels more effortless :D

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys Well, it avoids creating a custom orientation by using the ones that are already in Blender.

Answer (score 2):

To make the edge longer, press double <kbd>G</kbd> to slide, and to extend beyond the vertex limit press <kbd>C</kbd>. Or duplicate the edge and use the *Snap to Vertex* and *Auto Merge* options to merge the edges:

[image]

In both cases unfortunately you can't set the exact length (maybe with some addons).

Comment: @Lemon Yes you were right I had a doubt and when I tried it seemed to work, but bad answer

Comment: Thanks! While pressing double ```G``` does allow me to extend a line, the scale of any number I type to specify the amount of the extension will be in reference to the original line length - I'd like to use actual length here. The extrusion with ```E``` and ```Z``` with ```Transformation orientation``` set to ```Normal``` only works if the line is in line with the objects origin point.

Comment: @moonboots, suggestion, select both points, having the one on the cube corner active. Subdvide, then scale 2 (with pivot point as active)... if n subdive, scale to the amount of resulting segments.

Comment: @lemon I'm not sure what you mean, maybe write an answer?

Comment: @LukasFun yes maybe you can set the length with some addons, and my first answer was bad of course, the vertex normal doesn't follow the edge direction   ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is an addon that does it.

[image]

Select the edge, use <kbd>W</kbd> then use the menu as below:

[image]

Once validated, you can enter the length directly in the operator panel:

[image]

Comment: This seems to work, although ```W``` doesn't do anything for me. Do you have your controls set up so that is brings up the context menu or what is ```W``` for here?

Comment: @LukasFun `W` is an old shortcut for the context menu, now it just circles through the _Select_ modes. Simply right-click in the _3D Viewport_ to bring up the context menu.

Comment: Unlucky side effect: This scales with object scale. So unless I make the scale of my object 1 in every dimension, I will have to manually calculate this anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This is an addition to Lemon's answer. There is another way to use that addon.

Instead of using that method, if you open the N panel and click on the Edit tab:

[image]

Opening the Edge Tools dropdown gives you these options:

[image]

Selecting Edge Length gives you these options:

[image]

With the edge selected the Target Length gives you the current length of the selected edge:

[image]

You enter the length you want and choose the Resize Behavior. In this case I chose Counterclockwise:

[image]

This is what I got:

[image]

The Resize Behavior isn't very intuitive for me. I often have to redo it to get the edge extended in direction I want.

Answer (score 0):

So I thought that the normal of the vertex will point in the direction of the edge, and you can just change Transform Orientation mode to Normal and extrude in Z direction:

[image]

But as LukasFun pointed out in the comments, Transform Orientation set to Normal mode only points in a line from the origin to the vertex. It's still possible to use this to our advantage. One would just need to set the origin to the opposite vertex of the edge. If you have 3D Viewport Pie Menus addon enabled with Origin Pie menu, that's quite easy and quick to do and works from Edit Mode.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The extrusion with ```E``` and ```Z``` with ```Transformation orientation``` set to ```Normal``` only works if the line is in line with the objects origin point.

Comment: :D I did not know that.

Answer (score 0):

Select 2 vertices that represent the direction and then press <kbd>E</kbd> to Extrude then <kbd>S</kbd> to Scale. And then unselect the vertex you want to keep and press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Delete Vertex*. If you want to make sure it is the same length press <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]