# How can I extrude a vertice/edge in the same angle as its origin it extruded from?

Tags: vertices, edges, extrude

How can this extruded edge line up in the exact same angle as the vertex/edge it originates from?

[image]

Comment: maybe some annotations would help to show what you mean. If i understood you right...just extrude both vertices?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/291485/make-line-longer-extrude-vertex-along-line

Comment: Thank you John Eason this will do the trick :)

Comment: Which one? There are five different answers in that posting! :^)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/298649/142292

Answer (score 2):

If you create an orientation from an edge, or any 2 points, its Y is the vector between them:

[image]

Below, 'Create Orientation' is added to the Quick Menu. If you use it a lot, you might want to check 'Overwrite Previous' on first use, in its <kbd>F9</kbd> panel.

[image]

Above, the result of <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if there is another way, but I usually create another vertex and then tap <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> then press <kbd>Alt</kbd> to move it beyond.

First make sure *Auto Merge* and *Split Edges* are ticked

[image]

[image]

Comment: That just resets the vertex to its original position for me unfortunatwly

Comment: when you press `GG` you can move the vertex, then hold down `Alt` while you are moving the vertex and move beyond. Then left click to confirm, and then you can release `Alt`.